# Routing webserver access between LAN and VLAN

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, vlan

I have a LAN set up with IPs 10.0.0.X and a VLAN with 10.147.18.X (Zerotier) and I have a webserver (Plex) that is accessible within the VLAN. I have a ubuntu 22.04 pc connected directly to the LAN through ethernet interface and on a virtual interface this same pc is connected to the VLAN. How can I use the pc to allow computers on the LAN to access the webserver on the VLAN? I don't necessarily want to bridge the two networks because I don't want all traffic to go between these two LANs but only access to the webserver. I figure this would be possible with iptables or ip routing but I'm not sure how. Some of my devices are not able to use Zerotier so they can't directly connect to the VLAN.

Essentially I would like it so that when I open a web browser and access the IP address of the ubuntu pc at a specific tcp port on the LAN (e.g. 10.0.0.2:32400) it acts the exact same as if I was on the VLAN and I had put the address for the plex server with the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a port forward pretty simply with the following `iptables` rules (with `10.147.18.X` updated to the address of your target server)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.2 -p tcp --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-destination=10.147.18.X
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.147.18.X -p tcp --dport 32400 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then you'll need to enable IP forwarding with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. This configuration is ephemeral and will be reset on a reboot, so you might want to look into how to set up `iptables` rules and IP forwarding on boot.

You might also consider doing it with routing, if you set up the appropriate routes on the client and server machines you won't need any port forwarding rules.

```
# On the client
ip route add 10.147.18.0/24 via 10.0.0.2

# On the server
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.147.18.Y
# (update via IP to the IP of your ubuntu machine on the VLAN)

# On the Ubuntu machine, enable IP forwarding
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

This will allow devices on your `10.0.0.0/24` LAN to access devices on the VLAN using their IP addresses